# Tablesorter Filter with Quicksearch Plugin Issue for Showing Corresponding Contents

Tags: jquery-plugins, tablesorter, quick-search

I am trying to make the table shows the corresponding contents when I pick a category. I have that successfully implemented. However, if I search in the search box (using the quicksearch plugin) after I pick a category, it will search all the rows in the table rather than only searching for corresponding contents. How do I make it so, it will only search the corresponding items?

`Here is the demo`

http://jsfiddle.net/azsuA/

**UPDATED** Question

Now I have one child row under Coke in the table. I am wondering why is it being counted as "filteredRows"? How do I make "filteredRows" not including the child rows in the table? And for some reason, if I pick "Uncategorized", it'll say "1 - 1/ 1 (1) / 14" where it should be "- / (14)"

`Another demo`

http://jsfiddle.net/azsuA/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to disable, then re-enable quicksearch on the new categories ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/azsuA/1/)). First set up quicksearch like this:

```
/**
 *  Filter the table.
 *  Resource: https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch
 */
var quickSearchOptions = {
    show: function () {
        $(this).show().removeClass('filtered');
        $('table').trigger('pageSet'); // reset to page 1 & update display
    },
    hide: function () {
        $(this).hide().addClass('filtered');
        $('table').trigger('pageSet'); // reset to page 1 & update display
    },
    onAfter: function () {
        $('table').trigger('update.pager');
    }
};
$('.search').quicksearch('table tbody tr', quickSearchOptions);
```

Then, when you select a cateogy, disable, then re-enable quicksearch:

```
/**
 *  Show the corresponding contents when a category is clicked.
 *  Resource: http://tinyurl.com/jvneeey
 */
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {
    var filters = [],
        $t = $(this),
        col = $t.data('filter-column'), // zero-based index
        txt = $t.data('filter-text') || $t.text(); // text to add to filter

    filters[col] = txt;
    // using "table.hasFilters" here to make sure we aren't targetting a sticky header
    $.tablesorter.setFilters($('table.hasFilters'), filters, true); // new v2.9
    // disable previous quicksearch
    $('.search')
        .off('keyup')
        .quicksearch('table tbody tr:not(.filtered)', quickSearchOptions);
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, this totally works great. You're genius! thanks a lot!!

Comment: I have another question for you. It has been posted in the above under **UPDATED**. Thank you.

Comment: Are you adding the [child row class name](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#csschildrow) to that row? Also, check out the [`filter_childRows` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-childrows) - set it to `true` to include child row contents in the search.

Comment: Yes, in the second jsfiddle shows that I have added the class "`tablesorter-childRow`" on line 29. And `filter_childRows` is set to `true`.

Comment: have you had a chance to check my problem out? @Mottie

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy... I did look at this today, but I have yet to find a solution.